# Apparat AS3 issue

Tags: actionscript-3

Im using FDT trying to get an apparat application running where one of my classes extends apparat.inline.Macro, however, i'm getting the error

The definition of base class Macro was not found.

Any idea's

http://code.google.com/p/apparat/wiki/MacroExpansion

please note that all libraries(apparat/scala/flex) and swc's are added correctly

Comment: Maybe it will be better if you post into the group ? : http://groups.google.com/group/apparat-framework

Comment: Do you see the library in the external libraries? If there is an apparat.swc, try click the plus and see if you find the Macro class.

Comment: Cheers guys. I figured it out.

Comment: You should post your solution :)

Comment: You should post your solution

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my solution. I get this runtime error:

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class apparat.inline::Macro could not be found.
```

It's located here, so make it sure it's added in your src folder:

http://github.com/joa/apparat/blob/master/apparat-ersatz/src/main/as3/apparat/inline/Macro.as

Due to some strange reason it doesn't get added to the compiled swf, so to enforce it gets reference it adding the following line directly in your as entry point, or whereever you want:

```
var m:apparat.inline.Macro;
```